# CSS aspect-ratio media queries with no overlapping?

Tags: css, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to toggle 1:1 and 16:9 `<video>` elements using display block/none and aspect-ratio-media queries, but can't figure out how to eliminate potential AR overlap.

Here is my CSS and there is [theoretically] overlap when the AR is exactly 4/3. That said, I don't ever see both videos using these queries, but I'm concerned a client with exactly a 4/3 AR will show both videos.

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  video.mobile {
    display: none;
  }

  video.desktop {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  video.mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  video.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about changing one of them to include the 4/3 aspect ratio? E.g. `@media (aspect-ratio: 4/3 AND max-aspect-ratio: 4/3)`

Comment: The way you coded it, even if there is an overlap, the 2nd query (`max-aspect-ratio: 4/3`) should win out, which means `.mobile` will show and `.desktop` will be hidden. So I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right! The conditions of both media queries will be met at an exact aspect ratio of 4:3.

The cascading nature of CSS, however, plays to our advantage here. The styles declared in the latter media query will overwrite anything declared in the former media query.

This means at an exact aspect ratio of 4:3, `video.desktop { display: none; }` from the latter media query will be applied and thus hide the desktop version of your video.

To test the aspect ratio for yourself, run the following code snippet in full page view, launch the Device Toolbar in Chrome DevTools and set viewport dimensions to 640x480.

```css
div {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: silver;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
    .mobile {
        background: lime;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
    .desktop {
        background: lime;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile"></div>
<div class="desktop"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is in a React app I'm building and I'm realizing I have other issues with handling playback and refs and what if someone starts the video when it's 1:1 but stretches their browser out and it swaps the playing video with the 16:9 that isn't playing. I've posted a separate question for this. :)